# How to quickly identify Circular dependencies in React-Native

Tags: react-native, npm, circular-dependency

In a React-Native project using NPM, is there a quick way to identify Dependency cycle problems (aka when lint gives out an error of "cycle dependency detected"?

I am looking for something similar to this:
https://spin.atomicobject.com/2018/06/25/circular-dependencies-javascript/
(Or simple to follow instructions on how to use that plugin under react/npm)

Comment: I am trying to find something that works with react-native too, but maybe https://github.com/acrazing/dpdm can work with shellscript + husky, as this might throw and exit code when a circular dependency problem is found `npx dpdm  ./src/* --circular --exit-code circular:1 --warning false`

Answer (score 6):

I currently use the [dpdm](https://github.com/acrazing/dpdm) lib to check for circular dependencies on the react-native project.

Example:

```
npx dpdm ./src/* --circular --exit-code circular:1 --warning=false
```

With error:

```
✔ [718/718] Analyze done!
• Circular Dependencies
  01) src/services/index.ts -> src/services/Rating/index.ts
```

No error:

```
✔ [719/719] Analyze done!
• Circular Dependencies
  ✅ Congratulations, no circular dependency were found in your project.
```

CircleCI script fails if any circular dependency is found:

```
check-circular-dependency:
executor:
  name: react-native/linux_js
  node_version: '14'
steps:
  - checkout-and-attach-workspace
  - run:
      name: Check for Circular dependency
      command: npx dpdm ./src/* --circular --exit-code circular:1 --warning=false --tree=false
```